# Run transferred SmartWatch applications

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I've compiled some of the Sony SDK samples for the SmartWatch (SampleControlExtension and SampleWidgetExtension) This has worked fine and I've transferred them to a Xperia Z with a SmartWatch connected. I can however not find them among the SmartWatch applications on the phone or anywhere else. What am I missing?

I could add that I'm using Eclipse with the Android plugin. The Xperia is running 4.1.2 and the SmartWatch the latest version of the firmware.

Sincerely,
Gustaf

Answer (score 0):

It won't appear with your other apps, but at the very least, it should appear on the list of applications if you go to Settings->Applications->Manage applications. If it doesn't, then you've not transferred it correctly, assuming it is in this list:

I have experienced some issues with applications being discovered the first time when deployed by eclipse (adb).

Try restarting your device. Just the first time, as once it's on the SmartWatch application list, you won't have the same trouble.

Comment: They are indeed listed under Settings->Apps. They won't show up in the SmartWatch control app though.  Also I tried restarting the phone with no luck.

Comment: I'm also getting a lot of errors in the res files, @dimen for example when I import the projects. Maybe my setup is wrong somehow.

Comment: @GustafLindström but you fixed those errors? Otherwise I don't understand how you could have compiled and installed it with errors.

Comment: I did yeah by replacing them with absolute values instead of smart_watch_control_width for example.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually. The problem was how I referenced the SmartExtenstionAPI and SmartExtensionUtils.